# PGSQL + Encryption for specific columns

Tags: postgresql, encryption, cryptography

I am looking for a working example/implementation which best describes following lines direct from [one of the PGSql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/encryption-options.html):

> ### Encryption For Specific Columns
>
> The /contrib function library pgcrypto
>   allows certain fields to be stored encrypted. This is useful if only
>   some of the data is sensitive. The client supplies the decryption key
>   and the data is decrypted on the server and then sent to the client.

I know we can apply functions like crypt()/pgp_sym_encrypt() in INSERT sp to encrypt a value before inserting a record and decrypt in GET stored proc.

But as per the documentation, is there any direct way that automatically encrypt values if its given in INSERT statement and decrypt value if referred in SELECT statement? Is there any such column type which exist like a "encrypted column";   and provide data based on client supplied decryption key?

Or what I mentioned earlier to manually apply function to encrypt/decrypt data is the only correct way to store/retrieve data using the /contrib pgcrypto library?

Comment: no - but you can create  aset of triggers to automate it

Comment: @VaoTsun A trigger to automate decryption when a value is selected?

Comment: no - inserted  or updated more like. selects can be tweaked with rules or set-of-returning functions. Sorry - I thought OP was asking about how to store - yes see now **and decrypt value if referred in SELECT statement** I should have commented on it as well